# Use REST in R, httpPUT method

Tags: r, rest, http-put

I am implementing an application on R and now I'm trying to use REST protocol to communicate with an external application interface. It allows the app because this interaction has indicated in its documentation. I'm using a library called RCurl. Specifically I am using the function httpPUT. I have no idea about I'm doing wrong, but there is no change in the parameter that I want to modify it. My function is:

```
httpput_power<-function(DF_DEVICE_IDE_value){
  require(XML)
  require(RCurl)
  power<-""
  host<-"http://localhost:3171/devices/"
  id_devices<-DF_DEVICE_IDE_value[1,1]
  reader<-"/reader/parameter/RF_READ_POWER"
  half_url<-paste(host,id_devices,"")
  full_url<-paste(half_url,reader,"")
  url_reader<-gsub(" ","", full_url , fixed=TRUE)
  request="14.5"
  httpPUT(url_reader, request)
 }
```

Does anyone know a library for REST in R?. I not sure if RCurl is the most suited to do this task.
then there is an example in the documentation for the application to do a PUT with REST:

```
 PUT http://host_address:3161/devices/{device-id}/reader/parameter/
    {PARAM_NAME}
The value of the parameter.
Example: 30.5

Example:
    <result>
    <class>
    com.keonn.impl.protocol.DefaultISO18000_6CParameters$Filter
    </class>
    <noFilter>false</noFilter>
    <active>false</active>
    <truncate>UNSPECIFIED</truncate>
    <mask>
    <bank>EPC</bank>
    <pointer>32</pointer>
    <maskLength>2</maskLength>
    <mask>FF00</mask>
    </mask>
    </result>
```

I'm sure the URL is generated correctly, and in my case the parameter is RF_READ_POWER

Comment: So, the `XML` library will get you parsing. This http://technistas.com/2012/06/11/using-rest-apis-from-r/ provides an intro, but is not `PUT` related. This http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_curl shows a bit of how to form `PUT` requests with `cURL` and shld translate well to `RCurl`. Plot.ly has a pretty simple REST API that they've put into R http://plot.ly/api/r/getting-started/installation and might be something to take a look at to use to interface to your RFID reader/robot.  We'd need a link to the REST API docs to know more how to help (IMO).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the info, I have been studying the libraries that you mentioned me. In this link I provide you the reader documentation. On page 10 explains that options REST interface allows the reader, on pages 50-58 there are different parameters of requests and the last pages (115-end) are examples of requests. All advice is welcome.https://mega.co.nz/#!rwZQTRqS!1bg3Zth_9-SiJ1md6MBxY1wGqeVcZx_QPGh2gAUzIb0

Comment: For now, in regard to my needs, I think the only package that could be useful to me is the RCurl package with httpPUT function .... If you have any better idea to make a REST PUT request type, such as indicated in the documentation, please do not hesitate to comment on it, an example would be very helpful because I am a newbie to the R language